# ROS RT300 Force_Torque Sensor Connection with UR5 and ROS

Tags: ros-kinetic, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a UR5 and Force Torque Sensor FT300 setup. My sensor and UR5 Connected to main PC, which is inside same network as ROS Computer. I would like to receive FT300 topics, but I am not sure how.. In the same UR5 robot I also have a gripper with the same architecture, however with calling a Ros Service I could be able to communicate with Gripper. But I couldn't find a solution for my RT300 sensor.

I installed ROS Robotiq as a package to my workspace..

Could you please give me some guidance?

Best,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321812/ros-rt300-force_torque-sensor-connection-with-ur5-and-ros/) by [Meric](https://answers.ros.org/users/40534/meric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2019-04-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2019-06-13**:
Have you tried the Python script in this app? https://blog.robotiq.com/streaming-data-from-ft-sensor

**Comment by [Meric](https://answers.ros.org/users/40534/meric/) on 2019-06-23**:
Hello I tried and wrote my own python code. Please check my git.

https://github.com/AhmetMericOzcan/FT300-FT150-Reading-Sensor-Data-with-Universal-Robot-Controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
I talked with FT Sensor company. From what they say you need direct connection to do this. However if you have a pc inside the same network you can use python socket library, and listen sensor data.

For this issue please check my git. You can also eaisly modify my code. This code coming from FT300 guides, however I modified it as a rostopic.

https://github.com/AhmetMericOzcan/FT300-FT150-Reading-Sensor-Data-with-Universal-Robot-Controller

---

Originally posted by [Meric](https://answers.ros.org/users/40534/meric/) with karma: 23 on 2019-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2019-06-23**:
I also looked into it and can confirm that the UR controller just streams the data via Ethernet, and you can read it with a Python script fairly easily.